# Task List: display View Selector in Calendar view

Tags: sharepoint-online, task-list, calendar-view

SP Online, classic view, Oslo.

I've added multiple views to this Task list and even customized each view to display more options in View Selector:

[image: View Selector menu]

However, the Calendar view hides the View Selector:

[image: Calendar view]

Help please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a by-design behavior as you can always change your view in the ribbon. If you do not want to use ribbon, you will need to add scripts or insert links for redirecting.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! My main issue is that our end-users are rather new to SharePoint and I wanted to reduce the amount of instructions on how to navigate the site (this library is 1 out of 16 new features I'm building for them, so simplicity would be best). I could edit the page and create links (thanks for that idea!), but was hoping there would be a script that would "reveal" the view selector, assuming the Calendar view just "hides" it.

Comment: @Vico Per my knowledge, if you want to have a view selector instead of adding links for views, you will need to create the custom web part by yourself.

Comment: I've seen examples for similar code, but I'm not a coder at all -- just understand enough to edit code to address my situation, but I haven't found anything online that could be "easily" tailored. While having the direct script would be great, if anyone could just point me in the right direction of what tags I'm looking for, I can go fish :) Thank you all!